# Is it legal to translate an article without author's' permission

Tags: copyright

There many articles in the web

if I translate an article to another language and put it in another website (with mentioning the source)

will it be illegal to do that?

Do I need author's permission before doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is illegal unless it is out of copyright under the laws of the U.S. and most other countries, unless you have the permission of the copyright owner.

A few countries allow a translation to be made into one of their national languages if one is not made within a certain number of years and a request to do so does not cause one to be made, without violating their country's copyright laws.